# read function in C returns 0 even it is not the EOF

Tags: c

I am reading the book "Hacking: The Art of Exploitation". There is a small program that reads /var/notes, which is a binary file generated by myself, to search and output for some strings. However, the read function in function print_notes always returns 0, and the note_buffer is not touched at all. So, every time I get some unreadable output from the console like this:

```
$ ./notesearch                       
[DEBUG] found a 10 byte note for user id 1000
�w}�-------[ end of note data ]-------
```

The content of /var/notes is:

```
$ sudo hexdump -C /var/notes
00000000  e8 03 00 00 0a 61 61 61  62 62 62 63 63 63 0a     |.....aaabbbccc.|
0000000f
```

The first 4 bytes stand for an integer (in this case, 1000) and the rest are just ASCII code.

This program is for learning setuid, so the file permissions are set as below:

```
$ ll ./notesearch /var/notes     
-rwsrwxr-x 1 root root 22K Nov 19 22:23 ./notesearch
-rw------- 1 root root  15 Nov 19 22:22 /var/notes
```

Does anyone know why the read function always returns 0? By the way, I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and GCC 9.3.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include "hacking.h"

#define FILENAME "/var/notes"

int print_notes(int, int, char *);   // note printing function
int find_user_note(int, int);        // seek in file for a note for user
int search_note(char *, char *);     // search for keyword function
void fatal(char *);                  // fatal error handler

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int userid, printing=1, fd; // file descriptor
    char searchstring[100];

    if(argc > 1)                        // If there is an arg
        strcpy(searchstring, argv[1]);   //   that is the search string
    else                                // otherwise
        searchstring[0] = 0;             //   search string is empty

    userid = getuid();
    fd = open(FILENAME, O_RDONLY);   // open the file for read-only access
    if(fd == -1)
        fatal("in main() while opening file for reading");

    while(printing)
        printing = print_notes(fd, userid, searchstring);
    printf("-------[ end of note data ]-------\n");
    close(fd);
}

// A function to print the notes for a given uid that match
// an optional search string
// returns 0 at end of file, 1 if there are still more notes
int print_notes(int fd, int uid, char *searchstring) {
    int note_length;
    char byte=0, note_buffer[100];
    
    note_length = find_user_note(fd, uid);
    if(note_length == -1)  // if end of file reached
        return 0;           //   return 0

    read(fd, note_buffer, note_length); // read note data
    note_buffer[note_length] = 0;       // terminate the string
    
    if(search_note(note_buffer, searchstring)) // if searchstring found
        printf(note_buffer);                    //   print the note
    return 1;
}

// A function to find the next note for a given userID
// returns -1 if the end of the file is reached
// otherwise it returns the length of the found note
int find_user_note(int fd, int user_uid) {
    int note_uid=-1;
    unsigned char byte;
    int length;

    while(note_uid != user_uid) {  // loop until a note for user_uid is found
        if(read(fd, &note_uid, 4) != 4) // read the uid data
            return -1; // if 4 bytes aren't read, return end of file code
        if(read(fd, &byte, 1) != 1) // read the newline separator
         return -1;

        byte = length = 0;
        while(byte != '\n') {  // figure out how many bytes to the end of line
            if(read(fd, &byte, 1) != 1) // read a single byte
                return -1;     // if byte isn't read, return end of file code
            length++;  
        }
    }
    lseek(fd, length * -1, SEEK_CUR); // rewind file reading by length bytes

    printf("[DEBUG] found a %d byte note for user id %d\n", length, note_uid);
    return length;
}

// A function to search a note for a given keyword
// returns 1 if a match is found, 0 if there is no match
int search_note(char *note, char *keyword) {
    int i, keyword_length, match=0;

    keyword_length = strlen(keyword);
    if(keyword_length == 0)  // if there is no search string
        return 1;              // always "match"
    
    for(i=0; i < strlen(note); i++) { // iterate over bytes in note
        if(note[i] == keyword[match])  // if byte matches keyword
            match++;   // get ready to check the next byte
        else {        //   otherwise
            if(note[i] == keyword[0]) // if that byte matches first keyword byte
                match = 1;  // start the match count at 1
            else
                match = 0;  // otherwise it is zero
        }
        if(match == keyword_length) // if there is a full match
            return 1;   // return matched
    }
    return 0;  // return not matched
}
```

Comment: Your binary file is very curious. Why would you have a binary encoded integer in a file with newline characters? Are you simply using those for delimiters? Your debug output is off-by-one as you have 9-bytes in the note between delimiters (e.g. `"aaabbbccc"`) which makes `"[DEBUG] found a 10 byte note ..."` look at bit odd. It appears you want `while (read(fd, &byte, 1) == 1) { ... }` rather than prefilling `byte` and comparing to `'\n'` as the condition. There are likely other issues, but that stood out.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for some time, I finally find the reason. So, I am missing the #include <unistd.h>, if I include the header file, everything works fine.

I further searched for why this code could compile and run without including the header. It turns out that if GCC sees a function without declaration, it makes some assumptions on the function (one of them is returning an int). However, if the true definition of the function is different than the assumption, the program will have undefined behaviour. In this case, the true declaration for *lseek* is

```
extern __off_t lseek (int __fd, __off_t __offset, int __whence) __THROW;
```

but the compiler assumes the declaration be

```
int lseek(...)
```

Thus, the program has undefined behaviour since it would return the content from a register that normally stores the int return value.

By the way, the program could pass the linker because there's a function called *lseek* that fits the call in *print_notes* in the standard library.

Comment: If that's the case, did you not get an "implicit declaration" warning?  It is to warn you about exactly this case; it's a very serious warning that should not be ignored. (Though for that matter, neither should *any* compiler warning until you can prove that it's harmless).

Comment: @NateEldredge I did get some warnings, but I just ignored them. I was expecting the code would fail to compile if such missing declaration occurs since I am more used to c++.

Comment: Well then, lesson learned hopefully.  Missing declarations have been illegal in C since C99, but the standard only requires "a diagnostic" which is not required to be fatal.  Perhaps unfortunately, many compilers including GCC will just issue a warning and revert to C89 implicit int behavior.  So you do have to watch the warnings - and of course, there are plenty of other warnings that a compiler may issue for code that is perfectly legal C but not what you want.  Many people advise the use of `-Wall -Werror` so that warnings become fatal and you can't ignore them at all.